# Automtically add the partition key and a value to the partition key to a JSON file when Posting it into Postman

Tags: node.js, json, azure-cosmosdb

So I have many records (around 1000) with me that I want to insert into the cosmos DB. The partition key is **not** attached to them. Is there any way I can attach the partition key using the `.forEach(...)` method? in this case the partition key name is `firstname`.

Can we add the partition key and value to every record while posting it in Postman?

Is there anything I can code using `.forEach` to the attach the `firstname` to every record before it is stored into the cosmos db?

How would I modify the `insertCustomer` code to achieve the results?

Expected output:

```
{
    "shipment": [
        {
            "firstname": "abc",
            "id": "12345",
            "age": 23
        },
        {  
            "firstname": "bca",
            "id": "321",
            "age": 22
        }
    ]
}
```

Currently the data I have is like this:

```
{
    "shipment": [
        {
            "id": "12345",
            "age" :23
        },
        {  
            "id" : "321",
            "age" : 22
        }
    ]
}
```

app.js

```
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const employee = require('./router');
var app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(employee);


//CORS Middleware
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    //Enabling CORS
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, contentType,Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    next();
});


var ser = app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Server is running on port 3000..');
});
```

controller.js

```
const config = require("./config");
const CosmosClient = require("@azure/cosmos").CosmosClient;

const { endpoint, key, databaseId, containerId } = config;

process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
const client = new CosmosClient({ endpoint, key });

const database = client.database(databaseId);
const container = database.container(containerId);

class MainController {
    async fetchCustomers (req,res) {
        // <CreateClientObjectDatabaseContainer>
        const {endpoint, key, databaseId, containerId} = config;
        const client = new CosmosClient({endpoint, key});
        const database = client.database(databaseId);
        const container = database.container(containerId);


        try {
            // <QueryItems>
            console.log(`Querying container: Items`);
            const queryIterator = container.items.query(
            // query to return all items
                {
                    query: ' SELECT * from c '
                },

            { enableScanInQuery: true }
        );
            const { resources: items, requestCharge } = await queryIterator.fetchNext();
            const itemDef = items[0];
            console.log("Item '" + itemDef.id + "' found, request charge: " + requestCharge);
            res.json({resources: items, requestCharge});
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
        }
    }
    async insertCustomer(req , res){
        var params  = req.body;
        const { resource: createdItem } = await container.items.create(params);

        console.log(`\r\nCreated new item: ${createdItem.id} - ${createdItem.pk}\r\n`);
        res.json({ resource: createdItem })

    }
}

const controller = new MainController();
module.exports = controller;
```

router.js

```
const express =  require('express');
const controller = require("./controller");
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/api/fetchCustomers', controller.fetchCustomers);
router.post('/api/insertCustomer' , controller.insertCustomer);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have documents in your Cosmos DB container and you want to set the partition key value for those documents. Is that correct?

Comment: No, actually i have all the records with me around 1000. Now all these do not have the partition key attached to them. I thought instead of typing every single partition key for all 1000 records, can I use the forEach method to automatically assign the partition key when I POST the data in Postman.

Comment: Do the documents have the partition key value set or not? I am not able to understand what you're trying to do here. Please edit your question and explain that. Thanks.

Comment: Ok Ill edit my question. No the documents don't have the partition key set, they are just data that I got from the web and now I need to insert them into the Cosmos DB. Now, since we cannot insert the data into the Cosmos DB without the partition key, I need to add the partition key to all 1000 records and then send the data to the database. Instead of manually typing I thought I will use the forEach method in my code to automatically assign some value (of the partition key) and add it to the JSON file while Posting the data in Postman

Comment: Can you try something like `params['customerId`] = 'Some Value'` in your `insertCustomer` controller method. You'll need to add this line after `var params  = req.body;`. This assumes that your partition key attribute name is `customerId` and all the documents will have the same partition key value.

Comment: Oh ok, will try it out. Also I edited the question to help you understand better